# Extracting data from a 3D cell array into a 2D Matrix - MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have a cell array that is three dimensional i.e. 16x10x3 and I would like for all values in `:,:,1` `:,:,2` and `:,:,3` to be extracted into a column of a matrix each.

I thought about pre-allocating a matrix and then just running a basic loop such as:

```
for m=1:3
mat(:,m) = ([a{:,:,m}]); 
end
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this without having to rely on a loop?

EDIT: There are different numbers of values between :,:,1/2/3.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by single? do you mean that you have different number of elements in each cell? Or do you mean single as in float? If you do not have the same number of elements in each cell. Is it possible to guarantee that the matrix will have the right dimensions?

Comment: I've updated the OP with an example of part of the cell array. The values are all doubles however there are different number of entries for each of the third dimensions. For example :,:,1 can contain 150 entries in total while :,:,2 can contain only 90.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by whether or not we can guarantee that the matrix will have the correct dimensions.

Comment: And pad "empty" spaces with zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's high time you get into [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)! Here's the implementation -

```
%// Get the number of elements in each column of the input cell array
lens = sum(cellfun('length',reshape(a,[],size(a,3))),1)

%// Store the maximum number of elements possible in any column of output array
max_lens = max(lens)  

%// Setup output array, with no. of rows as max number of elements in each column
%// and no. of columns would be same as the no. of columns in input cell array 
mat = zeros(max_lens,numel(lens))

%// Create as mask that has ones to the "extent" of number of elements in
%// each column of the input cell array using the lengths
mask = bsxfun(@le,[1:max_lens]',lens)  %//'

%// Finally, store the values from input cell array into masked positions
mat(mask) = [a{:}]
```

Comment: I should have thought to use bsxfun after you showed me it yesterday! Thanks!